# JAWStats could not open an AWStats log file

Tags: apache-2.2, php, awstats

Since upgrading my PHP installation to 5.3, I have not been able to access jawstats with error:

> JAWStats could not open an AWStats log file
>
> Is the specified AWStats log file directory correct? Does it have a
>   trailing slash? The problem may be the variable "statspath" in your
>   config.php file.
>
> The data file being looked for is awstats20125.test.com.txt in folder
>   /var/lib/awstats/

When I check the contents of var/lib/awstats/ then month/year is in a different order. E.g: awstats052012.test.com.txt. From reading the [documentation](http://www.jawstats.com/documentation) I have made sure that I added statsname, although it doesn't seem to be taking any notice of this.

**Config.php**

```
  // core config parameters
  $sDefaultLanguage      = "en-gb";
  $sConfigDefaultView    = "thismonth.all";
  $bConfigChangeSites    = true;
  $bConfigUpdateSites    = true;
  $sUpdateSiteFilename   = "xml_update.php";

  // Default Site Config
  $config = array(
    "theme"       => "default",
    "fadespeed"   => 250,
    "password"    => "DGlxSLKT5k",
    "includes"    => "",
    "language"    => "en-gb"
  );

  // individual site configuration
  $aConfig["test.com"] = array_merge(array(
    "statspath"   => "/var/lib/awstats/",
    "statsname"   => "awstats[MM][YYYY].test.com.txt",
    "updatepath"  => "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/",
    "siteurl"     => "http://www.test.com",
    "sitename"    => "Test.com"    
  ), $config);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot, 5 mins after adding a bounty, I find that this error is caused because of the `open_basedir` being turned on.

Comment: How does open_basedir have to do with jawstats working?

Comment: Because open_basedir was preventing jawstats from reading the apache log files